My British passport was not stamped on leaving Italy, does that matter?
My British passport was stamped on entry to Italy on the 11th of October 2024, but when leaving Italy at the same airport on the 16th of October 2024, after the e-gates (explicitly marked as third country use) the border guard waved me through without a stamp to mark the exit. Is this likely to be a problem in future? If so, how would I go about getting my passport stamped correctly now that I'm back in the UK?

What's the issue here? Italy knows you left, as you successfully passed through the e-gates when leaving. The UK knows you're back home because you're back there now, and had to re-enter to get there. I don't see a problem.

@DavidRecallsMonica Italy presumably knows that he left, but since the electronic entry-exit system (EES) has been delayed and isn't yet in operation, there's no way for any other Schengen country to know except to look at the stamps in DavidTheWin's passport.  At least,, that's the official line.  (I would encourage you to leave your comment in place because many people will have the same question.)

Precisely @phoog, I'm going to apply for a visa to visit China next year and wouldn't want mismatched stamps to cause a problem in that process too

You won't be able to get it stamped.  However, the lack of a stamp only results in a presumption that you have overstayed, a presumption that may be rebutted with other evidence.  The chance of this actually causing a problem is quite small, but you could reduce it further by keeping with your passport any evidence you have of your departure from the Schengen area or your entry into the UK (or wherever else you might have flown to on October 16th).  If you want to be really well organised about it, you can type up a brief account of your experience with the e-gates and keep that together with your evidence.
Here's the relevant article of the Schengen Borders Code as it currently stands on October 21, 2024:

Article 12
Presumption as regards fulfilment of conditions of duration of short stay

Without prejudice to Article 12a, if no individual file has been created in the EES for a third-country national present on the territory of a Member State or the entry/exit record of that third-country national does not contain an exit date following the date of expiry of the authorised length of stay, the competent authorities may presume that third-country national does not fulfil, or no longer fulfils, the conditions of duration of authorised stay within the territory of the Member States.

The presumption referred to in paragraph 1 of this Article shall not apply to a third-country national who can provide, by any means, credible evidence that he or she enjoys the right of free movement under Union law or that he or she holds a residence permit or a long-stay visa. Where relevant, Article 35 of Regulation (EU) 2017/2226 shall apply.

The presumption referred to in paragraph 1 may be rebutted where the third-country national provides, by any means, credible evidence, such as transport tickets or proof of presence outside the territory of the Member States or of the date of expiry of a previous residence permit or long-stay visa, that he or she has respected the conditions relating to the duration of a short stay.
In the case of a rebuttal, the competent authorities shall create an individual file in the EES if necessary or indicate in the EES the date on which, and the place where, the third-country national crossed the external border of one of the Member States or the internal border of a Member State not yet fully applying the Schengen acquis but operating the EES in accordance with Article 20 of Regulation (EU) 2017/2226.

Where the presumption referred to in paragraph 1 is not rebutted, a third-country national present on the territory of the Member States may be returned in accordance with Directive 2008/115/EC of the European Parliament and of the Council ( *5 ).
A third-country national enjoying the right of free movement under Union law may only be returned in accordance with Directive 2004/38/EC.



Article 12a concerns the transitional details for the impending implementation of the electronic entry-exit system, EES.
As noted in the comments, this doesn't apply to Ireland, which has opted out of the Schengen area and related provisions (by contrast, a number of provisions of the Schengen Borders Code and Schengen Visa Code do apply to other non-Schengen EU states, for example the list of visa-exempt nationalities).

The OP's saying he left Italy through e-gates with a border guard waving him through suggests he was indeed leaving the Schengen area on that flight.

@DavidRecallsMonica indeed, but he could have been traveling to some other non-Schengen destination before returning to the UK.

@DavidRecallsMonica The border guard made a mistake, since presently the passport should have been stamped. The OP is now required to show 'credible evidence, such as transport tickets or proof of presence outside the territory of the Member States' when returning.

@MarkJohnson can you post where your quote comes from? My last trip to the EU was in 2016, and the only stamp in my expired US passport was stamped at the Dublin airport. It would be tough to find evidence of when I returned to the US.

@phoog can you add the source of your phrase "presumption that you have overstayed". I know in the past (2016) it wasn't normal to stamp passports when leaving Ireland.

@GerardAshton Ireland is not in the Schengen Area and has different rules compared to Schengen Area countries (and indeed, they do not stamp out, like the UK or the US for instance). At this time, all people subject to the 90/180 limit (to simplify, non-EU/non-Schengen nationals without residence permits) entering or leaving the Schengen Area must be stamped in and out, as this is the only way to know if one is within the 90/180 limit. This is supposed to change when the ever-delayed EES finally gets running.

@GerardAshton frankly I was hoping Mark Johnson would post an answer with the citation but I forgot to ask him to do that after he posted his comment.  Here I go...

@GerardAshton see item 3 in the quoted text, keeping in mind that the EES is not yet operating.  Many people use "EU" as imprecise shorthand for "Schengen area"; most significantly, Ireland (and formerly the UK) is entirely outside the Schengen area and is excluded from related legislation. The previous consolidated version, from 2017, has a somewhat different version of article 12 for pre-EES times, but it is essentially the same for this purpose: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/AUTO/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407.  I am not sure which version is technically in light of the delay.

...is technically in force today in light of the delay.

@phoog The sentence portion I quoted was taken from Article 12(3) Presumption as regards fulfilment of conditions of duration of short stay of the Schengen Border Code. Article 42a contains a fallback, where EES in not yet functional. Presently this is everywhere. The 11-15 date has be scrapped and the new plan is for the EES to be phased in where they are certain that no chaos situations occur (such as in Dover last year).
